# find unique lines based on one field only

Tags: bash, sorting, unique, uniq

Is there an easy way to find unique lines in a file (a switch for `uniq` perhaps?), but only considering a specific string/field?

For example, given the following:

```
1-3172  gi|493665175|dbj|AP012055.1|    100.000 136 0   0   115 250 64464   64329   6.78e-62    246
1-3172  gi|493665175|dbj|AP012055.1|    100.000 97  0   0   115 211 27885   27789   1.01e-40    176
1-3172  gi|500229602|gb|KC619528.1| 100.000 136 0   0   115 250 14268   14403   6.78e-62    246
1-3172  gi|514883433|gb|JX127248.1| 100.000 136 0   0   115 250 97570   97435   6.78e-62    246
1-3172  gi|514883433|gb|JX127248.1| 100.000 96  0   0   115 210 104503  104598  3.52e-40    174
1-3172  gi|514883433|gb|JX127248.1| 100.000 96  0   0   115 210 151929  151834  3.52e-40    174
1-3172  gi|514883433|gb|JX127248.1| 100.000 96  0   0   115 210 68038   67943   3.52e-40    174
1-3172  gi|514883433|gb|JX127248.1| 100.000 97  0   0   115 211 136361  136457  1.01e-40    176
1-3172  gi|514995431|gb|KC795685.1| 100.000 136 0   0   115 250 2358    2493    6.78e-62    246
1-3172  gi|514995435|gb|KC795686.1| 100.000 136 0   0   115 250 2358    2493    6.78e-62    246
```

I'd like to keep all the lines that have unique gi values in the second column (this is tab separated btw).

I've sort of achieved what I want with:

```
$ head pnf_blastout95.txt | sort -k 2 | cut -f 2-3 | uniq -u

gi|500229602|gb|KC619528.1| 100.000
gi|514995431|gb|KC795685.1| 100.000
gi|514995435|gb|KC795686.1| 100.000
```

But I'd like to keep the whole line in an ideal world? Without cutting, uniq considers them unique because of the scores and other info at the end of the lines.

The above is just the output of `head` to these files. The actual files are 15GB(!!!) in size (191494301 lines in one of them - hence me wanting to reduce it to unique matches), so whatever the solution, I could do with it being as fast as possible.

Comment: Ignore the duplicated lines totally (or) make them appear once?

Comment: Appear once, as they're still valid matches for the program that created this output.

Comment: Ah yeah, wasn't looking for awk solutions implicitly so didn't come across that one with my google-fu

Comment: Does awk require the file to be sorted first for this to work?

Comment: Not needed. `awk` can do the magic on its own